# Can Magento2 Enterprise see admin revenue

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, magento2-cloud, magento-2-commerce

I want to know if Magento2 team can see my revenue or have any kind of share if my store is on Enterprise. What access do they have if I move to Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise unlocks additional features of the platform via additional modules that are installed. The core Magento team do not have access to your installation, unless you ask them for support.

Andy pointed out that there is also a built-in backup system that could be utilized to provide a snapshot of your system to Magento for support. Utilizing this tool will provide them with a snapshot of your sales to that date.

---

When you purchase your license, you have to provide estimated (reasonably accurate) values for your store's performance (defined in section 5.2 of the license). Since you are providing the values each license renewal (section 5.3), your subscription price may vary. They also reserve the right to hire an independent auditor to look at your store's performance if they feel like you may be underreporting your sales values (section 5.4).

According to the [Magento Enterprise License](https://magento.com/legal/terms/enterprise-agreement):

> **5.2 Gross Merchandise Value, Average Order Value, and Subscription Fee adjustments.** Licensee acknowledges and agrees that the Subscription Fees specified in the Order Form are based on the GMV Threshold and AOV Threshold provided by Licensee prior or on the Effective Date
>
> **5.3 Provision of GMV and AOV information.** Licensee shall provide Magento written certification of Licensee’s then-current GMV and AOV (a) no later than within ten (10) days after the last day of each and every Contract Year and (b) upon receipt of written request by Magento during any Contract Year.
>
> **5.4 Audit Rights.** In addition to Licensee’s obligation set forth in Section 3, Magento reserves the right, no more than once per Contract Year and for a period of two (2) years after each Contract Year, to audit Licensee’s use of the Magento Services and Software and for the purpose of verifying any payments due under this Agreement for the preceding year

Now, that being said, there are provisions in the license which state that Magento will have access to Data Analytics (either Google or New Relic).

> **2.7 Analytics Data.**
>
> > **2.7.1 Grant of Access to Analytics Data.** Licensee shall do at least one of the following with respect to Analytics Data:
> >
> > (a) add Magento as a sub-account to Licensee’s Google Analytics account; or
> >
> > (b) add Magento to Licensee’s master New Relic, Inc. (“New Relic”) account for any new or existing New Relic extension installed in the Magento Software by Licensee.

So Magento has no access to your individual installation. The price is based on your own projections for the year. Magento is to have access to Data Analytics which may or may not include ecommerce tracking (you don't have to enable ecommerce tracking in Google Analytics unless you want to). Of course if Magento looks at your analytics data and sees that you're a very popular retailer and you're paying for a license based on around $100,000 in sales, they may audit your installation and adjust the pricing accordingly.

I would suggest you read and review the entire [Enterprise License Agreement](https://magento.com/legal/terms/enterprise-agreement) if you have any question as to what Magento can have access to regarding your data.

Comment: My question is basically if they can see our sales, reason is how they know our sales is $1M or above, because the various packages of enterprise is dependent on the sales.

Comment: https://www.grayboxpdx.com/blog/post/how-much-does-magento-2-cost

I know this is not official magento link, but how are they tracking sales

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't trust sources that aren't "official" from Magento when it comes to pricing.

Comment: Thank You very much, I will go through this. If anyone has any more points to add, feel free. I am assuming the case is same for Magento2

Comment: Magento could also get a glimpse into your sales if you engage their support services. They often request a copy of your code and DB so they can debug your issue. If you use the built-in backup system I believe it encodes some data (like passwords and such), but they would still be able to see sales history, etc.

Comment: I had originally mentioned using their support, but I guess my original edit chopped off the word "support". I've edited it also include providing them a backup of the system. Thanks @andyjv